# Android Unity3D VideoPlayer Playing video "from URL" not working properly

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Platform: Unity 2020.1.0f1

I have a weird problem while creating a little game that is meant to download videos from a remote URL to Application.PersistentDataPath and play them in the Unity3D-VideoPlayer using the "RenderTexture"-way by pressing a button for a specific video.

In the editor EVERYTHING works fine...

On IOS EVERYTHING works fine...

On Android (no matter which version) only the video from the asset folder is played properly. Accessing a downloaded file from Application.persistentDataPath is simply showing nothing on Android...

Things I checked (in addition to simple blindness):

- "External Write Permission" > forced everything on "internal"... not working
- Using Path.Combine() and/or "string filepath = ..."
- "Different Video Formats" > nope... the asset video is playing properly without transcoding (it is h.264 AVC, 650x650px, 30fps - AAC Audio, 44,1kHz, Bps 32)

Sample code below, the test scene can also be downloaded here:
http://weristaxel.de/upload/Videotest.unity
http://weristaxel.de/upload/VideotestController.cs

Video in Unity asset folder:
https://corolympics.azurewebsites.net/assets/game1howto.mov

What am I missing?

```
    public void PlayFromPersistent()
    {
// NOT WORKING ON ANDROID
        VideoPlayer VideoHowTo = VideotestCanvas.transform.Find("VideoPlayer").GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/game2howto.mov";
        VideoHowTo.Stop();
        VideoHowTo.url = filePath;
        VideoHowTo.source = VideoSource.Url;
        DebugText.text = "VideoHowTo.url = " + filePath;
        VideoHowTo.Prepare();
        VideoHowTo.Play();
    }

    public void PlayFromAssets()
    {
// WORKING ON ANDROID
        VideoPlayer VideoHowTo = VideotestCanvas.transform.Find("VideoPlayer").GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        VideoHowTo.Stop();
        VideoHowTo.clip = assetVideo;
        VideoHowTo.source = VideoSource.VideoClip;
        DebugText.text = "VideoHowTo.clip set -  original path " + assetVideo.originalPath;
        VideoHowTo.Play();
    }

    public void DownloadVideo()
    {
// THIS DOWNLOADS A TEST VIDEO TO "persistentDataPath"...
        string url = "https://corolympics.azurewebsites.net/assets/game2howto.mov";
        Debug.Log("Downloading " + url);
        var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET);
        string filename = url.Split('/').Last();
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath , filename);
        uwr.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerFile(path);
        uwr.SendWebRequest();
        DebugText.text = "Download to " + path + " finished";
    }

    public void AddListener()
    {
// NOT WORKING ON ANDROID - THIS ADDS A LISTENER TO AN EMPTY BUTTON TO EMULATE THE TARGET BEHAVIOUR
        Button button = VideotestCanvas.transform.Find("FromPersistentListenerButton").GetComponent<Button>();
        Color blueColor = new Color32(52, 152, 219, 255);
        button.GetComponent<Image>().color = blueColor;
        button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            VideoPlayer VideoHowTo = VideotestCanvas.transform.Find("VideoPlayer").GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
            string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/game2howto.mov";
            VideoHowTo.Stop();
            VideoHowTo.url = filePath;
            VideoHowTo.source = VideoSource.Url;
            DebugText.text = "VideoHowTo.url = " + filePath;
            VideoHowTo.Play();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still stuck i would try creating an independant function for when you add the listener event.  So it would be something like 'button.onClick.AddListener(() => IndFunction())' instead of creating a new instance each time. I was stuck on something similar a while back and i created an editable script for each button to store the info for each one and set each according to a list of image links and image names.